# Java MySQL integration with ArrayLists

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I am trying to get my program to be able to run over multiple runs. Meaning if I input something in my program and then shut it down, when I start it back up that info will still be there with the help of MySQL. I am fairly new to Java and MySQL but this is very important.
My program works perfectly but I have no idea how to get MySQL to hold the arraylist. I already have the database set up with everything I need. This is my MySQL bridge so far:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class SQL {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://instance23389.db.xeround.com:15296/Inventory","user","password");
    PreparedStatement Statement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from name");
    ResultSet result = Statement.executeQuery();
    {
        while(result.next())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and this line:

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
throws "Syntax error on token ""com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"", delete this token"
```

and I have already imported the correct files for the bridge.

I also tried the following code. It runs with no errors but it isn't importing the info from the database. Where do I go from there?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://instance23389.db.xeround.com:15296/Inventory","user","password");
        PreparedStatement Statement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from inventory");
        ResultSet result = Statement.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()) {
            // do something with the row
        }



    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=0;
    int choice;
    do{
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please select what you would like to do:\n1 = Add New\n2 = Update Inventory\n3 = Lookup Inventory\n4 = Make Changes\n5 = Totals");
            choice=input.nextInt();
            if(choice<1 || choice>5)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number 1-5.");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }while(choice<1 || choice>5);
        if(choice==1)
        {
            Product_Chart.newInv();
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            Product_Chart.updateInv();
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {

            Product_Chart.lookupInv();
        }
        else if(choice==4)
        {
            Product_Chart.MakeChanges();
        }
        else if(choice==5)
        {
            Product_Chart.Totals();// TODO does not call Product_Chart.Totals();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error 101");
        }
    }while(x==0);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you including the MySQL JAR in your build path?

Comment: Check your suitable driver is there or not . And MySQL jar as @Kevin Mangold  mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

is at the top level of the class - where you'd normally have variable declarations, methods, or constructors. You might want to put it in a static initializer:

```
static {
    Class.forName(...);
}
```

... although I thought that this step had been unnecessary for quite some time. (The driver discovery process has improved, basically.)

As for getting MySQL to "hold the ArrayList" - you need to insert, update or delete the contents of the database to match your data. It's too broad a topic to cover in a single answer, but you should read tutorials about how to modify data as well as just selecting it.

Comment: static block is not needed nowadays.

Comment: @vman411gamer -- you might benefit by taking a look at the Java Persistance API (JPA). A cheap approach would be to convert the list to XML using JAXB then storing the XML text in the database, too.

Comment: @Kevin Mangold -- so you think that I should use XML instead of MySQL?

Comment: I just need an easy way to store an arraylist between runtimes. I cannot believe this is that difficult! I have tried soooo much but to no avail!

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your code within a method. Try this, then "run" your class:

```
public class SQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://instance23389.db.xeround.com:15296/Inventory","user","password");
        PreparedStatement Statement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from name");
        ResultSet result = Statement.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()) {
            // do something with the row
        }
    }
}
```

If you code a main method like this (`static`, with `void` return type and a `String[]` parameter), you can then "run" your class.

Note that the line

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

is completely unnecessary: The driver will be loaded when you attempt to open your connection.